# Problems with database initialisation

Tags: database, flutter, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqflite

I'm making an app on flutter. I connect the database to the application and, when registering, I compare the username list with the input data and if they match, I should get an error. The problem is that instead of list with username I get "Instance of `'Future<List<ConnectifyModel>>>`, how to solve this problem, probably I have not written the query correctly.

db_handler.dart:

```
import 'package:connectify_app/model.dart';
  import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
  import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
  import 'dart:io' as io;
  import 'package:path/path.dart';


    class DB {
      static Database? _db;

      Future<Database?> get db async {
        if (_db != null) {
         return _db;
        }
        _db = await initDatabase();
        return null;
      }

  initDatabase() async {
    io.Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentDirectory.path, "Connectify.db");
    for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
      print(documentDirectory.path);
    }
    var db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDatabase);
    return db;
  }

  _createDatabase(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
      "CREATE TABLE users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL, username TEXT NOT NULL, email TEXT NOT NULL,password TEXT NOT NULL,city TEXT NOT NULL, bithday TEXT NOT NULL, hobbies TEXT)",
    );
  }

  Future<List<ConnectifyModel>> getAllUsernames() async {
      await db;
      final List<Map<String, Object?>> QueryResult = await _db!.rawQuery(
      "SELECT username FROM users");
     return QueryResult.map((e) => ConnectifyModel.fromMap(e)).toList();
  }
```

registration.dart:

```
 import 'package:connectify_app/db_handler.dart';
    import 'package:connectify_app/login.dart';
    import 'package:connectify_app/model.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_field_validator/flutter_field_validator.dart';

class Registration extends StatefulWidget {
  const Registration({super.key});

  @override
  State<Registration> createState() => _RegistrationState();
}


class _RegistrationState extends State<Registration> {
  DB? db;
  late Future<List<ConnectifyModel>> usernames;
  List usernameList = [];
  String? _name;
  String? _username;
  String? _email;
  String _password = "";
  String? _city;
  String? _bithday;
  String errorPassword = "";
  String errorUsername = "";
  bool isButtonActive = true;
  late TextEditingController controller;
  late TextEditingController _namecontroller;
  late TextEditingController _usernamecontroller;
  late TextEditingController _emailcontroller;
  late TextEditingController _passwordcontroller;
  late TextEditingController _citycontroller;
  late TextEditingController _bithdaycontroller;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    controller = TextEditingController();
    _namecontroller = TextEditingController();
    _usernamecontroller = TextEditingController();
    _emailcontroller = TextEditingController();
    _passwordcontroller = TextEditingController();
    _citycontroller = TextEditingController();
    _bithdaycontroller = TextEditingController();
    controller.addListener(() {
      final isButtonActive = controller.text.isNotEmpty;
      setState(() => this.isButtonActive = isButtonActive);
    });
    db = DB();
    loadUser();
  }

  loadUser() async{
    usernames = db!.getAllUsernames();
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    controller.dispose();
    _namecontroller.dispose();
    _usernamecontroller.dispose();
    _emailcontroller.dispose();
    _passwordcontroller.dispose();
    _citycontroller.dispose();
    _bithdaycontroller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.07,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.05,
              child: Text(
               "Регистрация",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 166, 10, 1),
                  fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.1,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.05,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            ),

            Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.1,
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.85,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (String value){
                        _name = value;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 166, 10, 0.6),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(20),
                      ),
                    ),
                        hintText: "Имя",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                    ),
                   ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.1,
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.85,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (String value){
                        setState(() {
                          _username = value;
                          print(_username);
                          print(usernameList);
                          print(usernames);
                          if (usernameList.contains(_username)){
                            errorUsername = "Такой никнем уже существует";
                            isButtonActive = false;
                          }
                          else{
                            errorUsername = "";
                          }
                        });
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 166, 10, 0.6),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(20)
                            ),
                          ),
                          hintText: "Ник",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.1,
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.85,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (String value){
                        _email = value;
                      },
                      // validator: MultiV,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 166, 10, 0.6),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(20)
                            ),
                          ),
                          hintText: "Email",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          helperText: "example@mail.ru",
                          helperStyle: TextStyle()
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.1,
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.85,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      obscureText: true,
                      onChanged: (String value){
                        setState(() {
                          _password = value;
                          if (_password.length < 6){
                           errorPassword = "Пароль должен содержать как минимум 6 символов";
                           isButtonActive = false;
                          }
                          else{
                            errorPassword = "";
                          }
                        });
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 166, 10, 0.6),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(20)
                            ),
                          ),
                          hintText: "Пароль",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          errorText: errorPassword.isEmpty?null:errorPassword,
                          // errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.1,
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.85,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (String value){
                        _city = value;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 166, 10, 0.6),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(20)
                            ),
                          ),
                          hintText: "Город",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.1,
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.85,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      onChanged: (String value){
                        _bithday = value;
                      },
                      controller: controller,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 166, 10, 0.6),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(20)
                            ),
                          ),
                          hintText: "Дата рождения",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        helperText: "ДД.ММ.ГГГГ"
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.07,
            ),
            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                foregroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 166, 10, 1),
              ),
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            Login()));
              },
              child: Text(
                  "У вас уже есть аккаунт?"
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.05,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.7,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  onSurface: Color.fromRGBO(171, 0, 144, 1) ,
                  backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(171, 0, 144, 1),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: (){},
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Зарегистрироваться",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.05
                    ),
                  ),
                ),),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`
I tried redoing the queries, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
  loadUser() async{
    usernames = await db!.getAllUsernames();
  }
```

Can you try adding 'await' here?

Define the list like this;

```
 late List<ConnectifyModel> usernames;
```

Comment: An error occurs;
A value of type 'List<ConnectifyModel>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<List<ConnectifyModel>>'.

Comment: late Future<List<ConnectifyModel>> usernames;   change to  late List<ConnectifyModel>